# Test Uniform Type Identifiers on the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, uti

The iOS simulator does not have the mail app. In light of this, is it possible to use the simulator to test one's custom Uniform Type Identifier (UTI)? Or does such testing have to be done on a device?

Answer (score 2):

I found three options:

- drag the file onto the simulator and your app should open.
- Sign into iCloud on the simulator, load an example of that file to iCloud, and you should be able to see your app when you try to open that file.
- Create a stub app that opens a url to an example of your file using [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller), or opens a url to your file using a [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller). In either case, your app should show up as option.

The first one is a little less work...

Comment: the dragging file tip is very convenient